# Coulomb's Law how to

Tags: distance, physics

I have testing in school for physics and this is the problem:

Two balls are electrified. First with: 20 µC and Secound with: 30 µC. Distance between them is 2cm and they are in vacuum. With what force balls refuse. Bad english sry.

k=?
Anyone? I dont know how to do this..

Comment: Wrong site, and even on the right one doubt anyone is going to do your homework for you without at least an attempt

Comment: This is not homework this is schoolend testing. But please if you know tell me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Pythonista already flaged ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mechanics, not programming

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, coulomb's law formula is:

[image]
Where **k** = 8.99×10^9 N m^2 C^−2 which is coulomb's constant. 

**r** is the distance of the two charges, and **q1** and **q2** is the magnitude of each respectively.

Comment: The one who downvoted this answer, please explain why.

Comment: Yep why.. Thanks <3 You saved my life xD

Comment: @TnTMark Hehe Thanks! Glad i helped ;) I hope your thread is moved to the correct forum because i am sure others have the same question! voteup'ed!